# Use Bootstrap with WebGrid column?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, webgrid

I've been searching for examples but can't seem to find how I can use Bootstrap inside of a grid column in order to create a button. The following works but I would like to display an Edit button instead of just the text.

```
@grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webgrid-table",
    headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
    rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style",
    alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",
    selectedRowStyle: "webgrid-selected-row",
    footerStyle: "webgrid-footer",

    columns: grid.Columns(
        grid.Column(columnName: "CustomerName", header: "Customer Name"),
        grid.Column(columnName: "Subject", header: "Subject"),
        grid.Column(columnName: "CallDate", header: "Call Date"),
        grid.Column(columnName: "Status", header: "Status"),
        grid.Column(header: "Edit", format: (item) =>
        {
            var link = Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id });
            return link;
        }),
```

Anyone know of an example I an look at to convert the Edit column to using a Bootstrap button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the `style` argument for that specific column like so:

```
grid.Column(header: "Edit", format: (item) =>
{
    var link = Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id });
    return link;
}, style: "btn btn-default")
```

Comment: This is definatley in the right direction but still seems to be a little odd. Using the code it fills up the whole column where is should be padding the cell with 7px. It might have to do with something in the CSS but there's not much CSS so I can't see if there is a problem with that.

Comment: @Caverman I have an MVC application that has a webGrid. The CSS is styled with Bootstrap and the button does not stretch for me. It's width is whatever the control's text spans. If you really need to, create a class with a specific padding and simply add it to the `style` property. That's another question for another day though! If my solution was what you were looking for, please mark it as an answer so that others may find it.

Comment: Could you post up some of your WebGrid/Bootstrap code? Or, any links you used for examples.